# MYSQL Table stuck on bad syntax error query

Tags: mysql

I was attempting to build a query which I already solved, however my "reservation" table is stuck with the previous query. When I open the list of tables of this database, I select the reservation one (it should take me to a page where all the reservations are shown), but instead of opening the page, it throws the following error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'ANDRESERVATIONDUEDATE=2017-03-2109:35:00 LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

I've tried to restart the service, stop it, restart the server, kill the MySQL process but nothing has worked yet. Any idea how can I make this query to un-stuck?

Comment: Presuming that you've copied the error message exactly, I'd say that the query snippet referenced, `ANDRESERVATIONDUEDATE=...`, is missing a space and should be `AND RESERVATIONDUEDATE=...`

Comment: Yes but the problem is I can't access the table anymore. It's stuck as if it were running the query still, I can't query that specific table.